# Displaying icons with exact size

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to have exact-sized icons on my map, where each icon takes up a predefined size in meters on the map. Additionally, these need to be changed at runtime, so generating an image ahead of time that covers the whole map is a no-go. My use case is displaying to-be-painted pavement markings, so a 3 meter square is probably the largest thing displayed. Matching the rotation and pitch is easily done with setting [`icon-rotation-alignment`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-icon-rotation-alignment) to `map`, leaving the issue of size. I could scale the [`icon-size`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-icon-size) by [`interpolate`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#interpolate)-ing the zoom factor (`['interpolate', ['exponential', 2], ['zoom'], 15, 1 / 72, 22, 1 / 0.56]`), but I would then run into problems with the [difference in latitudes with the Mercator projection](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/zoom-level/#zoom-levels-and-geographical-distance). It would probably be possible, though, to interpolate based on both the zoom and current latitude.

Alternatively, some demos that look to be doing similar tasks of aligning real-world sizes are [Add a 3D model](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/), [Add a canvas source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/canvas-source/), [Add a custom style layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-layer/) (although I don't think I need that), and [Add an image](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/). My understanding of how I would use each:

- Add a 3D model: I would use three.js (or another renderer) and set it up with the location and image of each symbol, then use it to draw.
- Add a canvas source: Either create a very large canvas (probably would use too much RAM) or one canvas per symbol (overhead?), then draw the symbol
- Add an image: Same decision, but with URLs instead of canvases

Which of these would be the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily with a raster layer in mapbox but you’ll need to do on your side the calculations of the length in meters for the 4 corners of the image using a conversion that considers latitude.

Other option if you want to add an image in exact meters size (considering the latitude), just check this out made with the latest version of [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/issues/136)

You’ll be able to load any image (and any 3D model) and define its size in meters (millimeters indeed) with only a few lines of code, but using a threejs plug-in for a pure 2D task is probably like shooting fish in a barrel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you think the overhead of ~100 layers and corresponding sources is fine or should I go with a separate 3D renderer?

Comment: With a quick test, I see that performance is pretty abysmal with 100 image layers. Will go with 3D.